# Gitkit - how to handle errors using custom UI?

Tags: android, google-identity-toolkit

Hi I'm using custom UI and I want to know how to handle errors.
The only known error I get from the API is ErrorCode.INVALID_PASSWORD,
but how can I know about other errors? There isn't any documentation I've found.

One problem I have is: after several failures to enter password on signIn, there is a need in CAPTCHA, how do I get the CAPTCHA.

This is my code for error handling:

```
@Override
public void handleError(UiManager.ErrorCode errorCode, Object...  objects) {

        if (errorCode == ErrorCode.INVALID_PASSWORD)
            Toast.makeText(this, "Error: Invalid Password", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        else {
            if (objects != null && objects.length != 0) {
                Toast.makeText(this, "Error: " + objects[0], Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you are building an android app. Setting up your own reCAPTCHA with that could be messy since reCAPTCHA will require a webview. The current identity toolkit android client code does not trigger reCAPTCHA on multiple incorrect password entries. You could use that or you could display your widget login webpage in a webview when reCAPTCHA is required. It would handle reCAPTCHA for you. On success, you could redirect to your native app.

Comment: Thanks. I didn't understand exactly: "The current identity toolkit android client code does not trigger reCAPTCHA on multiple incorrect password entries. You could use **that** or you could display your widget login webpage in a webview when reCAPTCHA is required. It would handle reCAPTCHA for you." what do you mean by that? I want that when a reCAPTCHA is required the app will lead to a webpage that will have the reCAPTCHA. how do I do that

Comment: You can follow the quick start https://developers.google.com/identity/toolkit/android/quickstart. Using the android sdk will not trigger the request for recaptcha. However that means that you won't be able to customize the UI. If that's a deal breaker, you can also set up your own website with the identity toolkit widget. Follow the quick start for web. Using CSS customization you can make it close to your android custom UI.

Comment: When you get a request for recaptcha after a user enters the password many times, display a webview or redirect to a browser with your website identity toolkit widget page. The user on login will be asked to complete the recaptcha. On success, you can redirect to your native android app.